# How to remove div element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I want to remove div element, I have the following code:

```
<div class='text-field'>
     <input type='text' />
     <input type='button' class='remove-btn' />
</div>
<div class='text-field'>
     <input type='text' />
     <input type='button' class='remove-btn' />
</div>
<div class='text-field'>
     <input type='text' />
     <input type='button' class='remove-btn' />
</div>
<div class='text-field'>
     <input type='text' />
     <input type='button' class='remove-btn' />
</div>
```

when i click remove-btn, its parent div text-field should be removed. i have this code but it doesnt work.

```
$(".remove-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

thanks for any help. :)

Comment: In what way does the code not work?

Comment: thanks for your response guys, sorry im kinda new to this. actually, im trying to do this http://jsfiddle.net/pV2Wr/

Comment: i cant see what's wrong with it

Comment: This works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pV2Wr/15/. 1) jsFiddle requires you to put only JavaScript code in JavaScript panel. 2) It executes the JavaScript code after DOM load, so that must be your problem. There are solutions posted about this.

Comment: remove button does not work well, thanks for the info anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment here is what you should do:

```
$("#add-file-field").click(function() {
    $("#text").append("<div class='text-field'><input type='text' /> <input type='button' class='remove-btn' value='remove' /></div>");
});

$(".remove-btn").live('click',function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: wow, you saved my day man! thanks a lot. thanks also for all your response guys. :)

Answer (score 4):

The most common cause for this is that you may be trying to bind to the click event before the element has been loaded in the DOM.  Try wrapping your jQuery code in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

There's also the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function which will bind to elements which are added to the DOM at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your javascript is loaded after [DOM load](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(function(){
 $(".remove-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
 });
});
```